# Load all JS and CSS before AJAX content rendering

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I need to load the JS and CSS before the Ajax page HTML render. here's the scenario:

1. I have two files `1.PHP` content below code - Basically it call the ajax :

> ```
> <script>
>
>     $('#loading_spinner').show();
>     var mydata = 105;
>     var post_data = "isln="+mydata;
>     $.ajax({
>         url: 'processpage.php',
>         type: 'POST',
>         data: post_data,
>         dataType: 'html',
>         success: function(data) {
>             $('.my_update_panel').html(data);
>             $('#loading_spinner').hide();
>         },
>         error: function() {
>             alert("Something went wrong!");
>         }
>     });
> </script>
> ```

2. processpage.php content the PHP code , JS & CSS

> ```
>     <meta charset="UTF-8">
>     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
>     <title>Brand Management</title>
>     <link rel=stylesheet type=text/css href='css/1.css'/>
>     <link rel=stylesheet type=text/css href='css/2.css'/>
>     <link rel=stylesheet type=text/css href='css/3.css'/>
>     <link rel=stylesheet type=text/css href='css/4.css'/>
>    
>     <script type='text/javascript' src='js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js'></script>
>     <script type='text/javascript' src='js/jquery-ui.min.js'></script>
>     <script type='text/javascript' src='js/scripts.js'></script>
>     <script type='text/javascript' src='js/mh-overlay.js'></script>
>     <script type='text/javascript' src='js/jquery.qtip.min.js'></script>
> </head>
>
>
>  <?php 
>        echo "My PHP CODE Process";
> ?>
> ```

**Issue:** when i load the pages it first execute my PHP code and after that it load all CSS and JS. but i want to load all JS and then load PHP code output

**Currently It Loads :**

> PHP Code Output
>
> JS1
>
> JS2

**I want it must be:**

> JS1
>
> JS2
>
> PHP Code Output

PS: I already tried with the `ajax.load()` and other available answer of this site , but it couldn't work!!!

Thanks in Advance!!!

Comment: use onload() to wait on the external assets

Comment: @dandavis can you please explaine or have some code example please?

Comment: `I need to load the JS and CSS before the Ajax page HTML render` It sounds like a XY problem: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem

Comment: @A.Wolff ... I think it would be but need to ask before i change the way. to make sure it possible or not.

Answer (score 1):

What you're asking is impossible. PHP code is executed by the server before the response, including the javascript code and css, is even sent to the client. You'll need several ajax queries to achieve what you're trying to.

Comment: I know that i can achive this by several code that load JS and all after that HTML or PHP output. but i am searching for something that's worked in one Ajax call only. anyway Thanks for your input.